# Как вызвать анонимную функцию из слайса (interface)?

Tags: golang

Всем доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся с необычной для меня задачей вызова функции из слайса `[]interface{}`. Обычный способ не помогает `slice[2]()`, а источники из интернета рекомендуют следующий способ:

```
action := reflect.ValueOf(&intef[1])
action.Call(nil)
// action.Call([]reflect.Value{})
```

Который вызывает следующую ошибку:

> http: panic serving [::1]:57927: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Call
> on ptr Value

Помогите пожалуйста найти решение данного вопроса, спасибо.

---

P.S.: Интересно то что, когда возвращаю тип данных, то все корректно отображается:

```
xType := fmt.Sprintf("%T", intef[1])
fmt.Println(xType) // *func()
```

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Инициализация данных:

```
type Route struct {
    Routes       map[string][]interface{}
}

func (route *Route) Get(path string, action func()) {
    method := "GET"

    route.Routes[path] = []interface{}{method, &action}
}
```

Передача необходимых данных в функцию/метод соответственно для вызова callback'a:

```
type Api struct{}

func (api *Api) Run(wri http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    router := core.HandleRouter{
        Req: *req,
        Wri: wri,
    }
    route := core.Route{
        Routes:       map[string][]interface{}{},
    }

    // User paths
    route.Get("/api/user/get", func() {
        wri.Write([]byte("Get user by Id=578"))
    })

    // Run Router Handle
    router.TunnelControl(&route.Routes)
}
```

Вызов функции из слайса:

```
func (hr *HandleRouter) TunnelControl(routes *map[string][]interface{}) {
    isNotFound := true

    for path, interf := range *routes {
        if hr.IsValidPath(path) {
            isNotFound = false
            method := interf[0].(string)

            if hr.IsMethod(method) {
                f_ptr, ok := interf[1].(*func())

                if !ok {
                    panic(
                        fmt.Sprintf("Неверный тип объекта: ожидался `*func()`, оказался `%T`", interf[1]),
                    )
                }

                (*f_ptr)()
                hr.Wri.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
            } else {
                hr.Wri.WriteHeader(http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
                hr.Wri.Write([]byte("Method Not Allowed\n"))
                hr.Wri.Write([]byte(method + ", must be passed\n"))
            }
        }
    }

    if isNotFound {
        hr.Wri.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
        hr.Wri.Write([]byte("404 Not Found\n"))
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите как вы инициализируете массив функций. Откуда там берется указатель на функцию?

Comment: Проблему свою я решил благодаря вам, но все же дополнил кратким исходным кодом, быть может кому-то будет полезным тоже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте приведение типа ([type assertion](https://go.dev/tour/methods/15)):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := []interface{}{
        func() {
            fmt.Println(1)
        },
        func() {
            fmt.Println(2)
        },
    }

    f, ok := x[0].(func())
    if !ok {
        panic("Неверный тип объекта")
    }
    f()
}
```

Выражение `.(func())` преобразует левую часть к типу `func()` и булевскому значению. Если приведение типа не удалось, булевское значение равно `false`

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Ок, у вас тип элементов не `func()`, а указатель на `func()`. Соответственно, приводить нужно к типу `*func()`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    functions := []func(){
        func() {
            fmt.Println(1)
        },
        func() {
            fmt.Println(2)
        },
    }
    pointers := []interface{}{
        &functions[0],
        &functions[1],
    }

    // Вызов через `reflect` - нужно сначала разыменовать указатель вызовом метода `Elem`
    ptr := pointers[0]
    reflect.ValueOf(ptr).Elem().Call(nil)

    // Вызов через приведение типа
    f_ptr, ok := pointers[1].(*func())
    if !ok {
        panic(
            fmt.Sprintf("Неверный тип объекта: ожидался `*func()`, оказался `%T`", pointers[0]),
        )
    }
    (*f_ptr)()
}
```

Заодно в примере показано, как вызывать через `reflect` - у вас значение типа *указатель* на функцию, поэтому перед вызовом указатель нужно разыменовать. Это делается вызовом метода `Elem`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Пробовал данный способ, к сожалению возвращает `false`.
Временно пользуюсь следующим решением `map[string]func()`

Comment: @DeveloperVusal у вас исходный пример был с указателем на функцию, соответственно вам нужно было приводить к типу `*func()`. Я добавил пример

Comment: Странно явление, я наверное за все это время много способов испробовал, что и возникала проблема с указателем, да, я указатель передавал для функции думал, тогда поможет, сейчас же попробовал как с указателем и без и все работает. Спасибо тебе большое за помощь:)